# Why is the page blank?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, reverse-proxy, centos7, mod-proxy

I have  Tomcat is running on Windows server 2012R2 and I have configured an application with the following URL
http://localhost:8080/app
i wish to put this app online so setup a SSL Reverse-Proxy

I am using Apache HTTPS Server As Reverse-Proxy Using mod_proxy Extension.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /app http://192.168.40.20:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://192.168.40.20:8080/app
```

I need to configure Apache to transfer requests to tomcat like below:

https://192.168.40.20/app/ >> http://192.168.40.29:8080/app/

but when i try to access the page i get a blank page nothing is showing

when i inspected page elements:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://192.168.6.136/lib/ueditorsrc/ueditor.config.js”.
insurance:16
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://192.168.6.136/lib/ueditorsrc/ueditor.all.js”.
insurance:17
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://192.168.6.136/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js”.
insurance:20
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://192.168.6.136/lib/ueditorsrc/angular-ueditor.js”.
insurance:21
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://192.168.6.136/js/app.js”.
```

screenshot of the page 
[image: page]

Comment: Proxying doesn't change your code,.. The requests are asking for `/lib/ueditorsrc/ueditor.config.js` and not `/app/lib/ueditorsrc/ueditor.config.js`  You would either need to change your HTML / javascript to reference `/app/lib*` or make all URL's relative..  'lib/*` instead of `/lib/*`

Answer (score 0):

found the solution it had to do with a forward slash i place in front of the ap/